# angular-js 2 or 3 ng-view for slide

Tags: angularjs

i need to add 2 o 3 slider to my page with angularjs by reading some json.
my code should be something like that:

```
 <div class="wrapper">
     <div id="navigation">...</div>

     <div class="slider">
        <ul class="painting">
            <li>
            <a href="#"><img src="img/01.jpg" height="240" width="237"/></a>
            <h1>title</h1>
            <h2>description</h2>
            </li>
            <li>...</li>
            <li>...</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="slider">
        <ul class="illustration">
            <li>
            <a href="#"><img src="img/01.jpg" height="240" width="237"/></a>
            <h1>title</h1>
            <h2>description</h2>
            </li>
            <li>...</li>
            <li>...</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

<div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

i code 2 template: one for the list of slide and one for the detail. I add ng-view to the first div.slider and when i click on the image, the details template is open inside the div.slider ..instead i need to clean all and print it inside the body.

By now, this is my index:

```
<div id="wrapper">
        <div id="navigation">...</div>

    <div id="portfolio" class="sliderCont first">
        <div ng-view class="slider"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="sliderCont">
        <div class="slider"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="sliderCont">
        <div class="slider"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="sliderCont last">
        <div class="slider"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is my list.html template:

```
<ul class="works">
<li ng-repeat="work in works">
    <a href="#/works/{{work.id}}"><img src="{{work.thumbUrl}}" height="240" width="237"/></a>
    <h1>{{work.testo1}}</h1>
    <h2>{{work.testo2}}</h2>
</li>
</ul>
```

my controller.js:

```
function sliderListCtrl($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('json/slider1.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.works = data;
  }); 
}
function sliderDetailCtrl($scope, $routeParams, $http) {
  $http.get('json/' + $routeParams.workId + '.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.work = data;
  });
}
```

and in the end, my app.js:

```
angular.module('workList', []).
config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.
  when('/works', {templateUrl: 'partials/work-list.html', controller: sliderListCtrl}).
  when('/works/:workId', {templateUrl: 'partials/work-detail.html', controller: sliderDetailCtrl}).
  otherwise({redirectTo: '/works'});
}]);
```

does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your question, but reading the title, 2-3 `ng-view`, that is not possible.

You can only have one `ng-view` per application, which normally contains the application itself.

If you want to add partial templates, you can use `ng-include` which allow you to add all the templates you want inside others.

On the other hand, there is a `ui-router` project which have a different way to add templates to your views.